# Delayed appearance of 2nd menu, after answer is entered in first menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I needed a secend menu to appear, prompted by the answer selected in the first menu. The second menu appears as it is supposed to, however it appears too quickly (as it appears before the first menu dropdown links disappear after selection). Some people don't notice that the second menu has appeared. I would like to delay the appearance of the second menu, if possible, maybe by 1 second. Can anyone help? I will paste a greatly condensed version of what I have so far below:

```
<div align="center"><font color="#000080" size="6"><strong>Step 1</strong></font>
<form>
    <select style="background-color: #f81414; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #ffffff; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold" id="opts" onchange = "showForm()">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Click Here to Select Brand</option>
    <option value="1">Bissell</option>
    <option value="2">Hoover</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br />
<div style="display: none" id="f1" align="center"><font color="#000080" size="6"><strong>Step 2</strong></font><br />
<form name="form1">
    <select style="background-color: #f81414; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #ffffff; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold" onChange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Click to Select Your Bissell Model</option>
    <option value="9400-proheat-2x-select-pet-deep-cleaning-series.html">Bissell 9400 2X Deep Cleaner Parts</option>
    <option value="9500-bissell-proheat-2x-.html">Bissell 9400 2X Deep Cleaner Parts</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
<div style="display: none" id="f2" align="center"><font color="#000080" size="6"><strong>Step 2</strong></font><br />
<form name="form2">
    <select style="background-color: #f81414; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #ffffff; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold" onChange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Click to Select Your Hoover Model</option>
    <option value="hoover-7069-conquest.html">Hoover U7069 Conquest Deep Cleaner</option>
    <option value="hoover-8055-conquest.html">Hoover U8055 Conquest Deep Cleaner</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function showForm(){
var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
if (selopt == 1) {
document.getElementById("f1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("f2").style.display="none";
}
if (selopt == 2) {
document.getElementById("f1").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("f2").style.display="block";
}
}

</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A setTimeout() will place a delay on whatever function you would like to delay.

```
if (selopt == 1) {
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("f1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("f2").style.display="none";}, 1000);
```

}

Notice the second parameter - "1000" -  is the number of milliseconds that will elapse before the code in the first parameter is run.  [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigbiff02/q5nRV/1/) with a 2 second delay.

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow.com. I don't see a "mark as answered" button??

Comment: Got it. One more question. Can't get the link boxes to work in Firefox at all. When I click them, nothing happens (http://www.vacsite.com/en/castex-1-2-3/castex-parts-by-machine-diagram2.html). Should I make that a new question?? Thanks again, Dave

Comment: Did you fix it?  Because initially the dropdown did not work for me in firefox.  Now it's working, must be magic.

Comment: Yes got it working. I had installed a no right click/no select sript in vacsite.com day before yesterday. The link box still worked in several browsers, but not firefox. Had to remove the no select portion of the script, and leave only no right click. Thanks again. All is well! Dave